# cannot resolve appcompatactivity in empty project

Tags: android-studio

I create empty project in android studio but every time I see this error. I have it in dependency.

Main Activity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

gradle:

```
 dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild or clean your project?

Comment: yes. but not help

Comment: Try `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Comment: Invalidate caches and restart Android Studio and voila problem solved.

Comment: not works @piotrek1543

Comment: Do you have this problem in only this project or in every project?

Comment: in every project. i found the problem. it was related to the version of dependency. I change dependency and it solved. so I don't know which version I should Use for each dependency.

Comment: I guess you should always try to use the latest version of the appcompat library. Currently this is 24.2.0

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me when i import a project to another pc, the solution that works for me every time is:

1.Close Project
2.Delete the .idea folder of your project
3.Open and Build your project
4.File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

Dears, I launch update from android studio: Help -> Check for Update... And Installed API level 23 Revision 3,
Then the project compiles as normal.

use the dependency-
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'

Comment: my android stadio is up date to the last version.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.In my case I solved the problem by adding

compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0"

Reference : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html

https://androidforums.com/threads/cant-not-resolve-symbol-appcompatactivity.1028667/